# seam-mail does not work on JBoss AS 6

Tags: seam, seam2, jboss6.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [seam-mail does not work on JBoss AS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862303/seam-mail-does-not-work-on-jboss-as-6)

Im using JBOSS Seam 2.0 and The application server is JBoss 6.. while sending mail

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException is thrown... Pls Help.. How to resolve this

Exception is

Exception in MailBean ::: sendMail  -> : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.administration.MailBean.sendMail(MailBean.java:572) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.administration.MailBean_$$_javassist_seam_9.sendMail(MailBean_$$_javassist_seam_9.java) [:]
    at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.administration.CompetencyMappingBean.sendMailToEmployees(CompetencyMappingBean.java:3442) [:]
    at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.administration.CompetencyMappingBean.notifyEmployees(CompetencyMappingBean.java:4025) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.security.SecurityInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:163) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.administration.CompetencyMappingBean_$$_javassist_seam_14.notifyEmployees(CompetencyMappingBean_$$_javassist_seam_14.java) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_13]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335) [:1.0_02.CR2]
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348) [:1.0_02.CR2]
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58) [:1.0_02.CR2]
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96) [:1.0_02.CR2]
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276) [:1.0_02.CR2]
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68) [:1.1.15.B1]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at com.ey.SkillTracker.bean.session.SessionIdFilter.doFilter(SessionIdFilter.java:73) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:118) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495) [:3.3.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentVa

Comment: Hello. You have pasted this same question twice (see duplicate). Doing so will not help you get an answer faster - actually it will likely dissuade people from helping you. You should take a look at the faq and about and have a look around the site to see what a "good question" looks like. Form yours in the same way and you'll likely get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have some probles with Seam 2.2.0 and JBoss 6. But there is the new version of Seam: 2.2.1. And as I see i that version all examples start working with JBoss 6.

Maybe solution for you will be upgrading Seam framework? At least you can check mail examples from the 2.2.1 library version, it should work.

[Seam 2 Distribution Downloads](http://seamframework.org/Seam2/Downloads)